# Getting Odd Results from my SQL Statement(s)

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I got different results when I repeated the WHERE statement (by mistake).

Today I was trying to look up how many times some errors were appearing in our system.  I got odd results when I repeated the same WHERE statement by mistake.  I first searched for error code 635 and got 140 returns.  So I attempted to search for two different error codes but mis-typed the second code in question to the same number as in the first WHERE statement, 635, and I got 1058 rows returned.

I'm curious why the 1058 rows didn't return when I only had the WHERE statement once.  I even experimented and repeated the WHERE statement three more times (four total) but the number of rows returned stayed constant at 1058.

I first ran this and got 140 rows returned...

```
SELECT *
FROM ErrTbl
WHERE status = 'unresolved'
AND ErrCd = '635'
```

Then I wanted to run this...

```
SELECT *
FROM ErrTbl
WHERE status = 'unresolved'
AND ErrCd = '635'
OR ErrCd = '735'
```

But I accidentally ran this and got 1058 rows returned...

```
SELECT *
FROM ErrTbl
WHERE status = 'unresolved'
AND ErrCd = '635'
OR ErrCd = '635'
```

If I accidentally repeated the same WHERE statement I would expect the returned rows to be the same, in this case 140.  Actually, looking at the returns it should have been 1058 for each case.

I'm not sure why the difference.

Comment: All you need is to replace that `AND` with an `OR`. A single row can't have two values for the same column (and), but them can have one value OR other value. BTW, I think that this where clause should return zero results, but looks like it's returning all rows of your table, and that's weird. Hope I can help you.

Comment: Never use OR without parentheses. `SELECT * FROM ErrTbl WHERE status = 'unresolved' AND ErrCd = '635' OR ErrCd = '735'` is not the same as `SELECT * FROM ErrTbl WHERE status = 'unresolved' AND (ErrCd = '635' OR ErrCd = '735')`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the ErrTbl is loaded, it might happen that the table was getting loaded while you first ran the below query and got 140 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM ErrTbl WHERE ErrCd = '635'
```

Next when we ran the below query, you got 1058 rows because the data might have changed in the table after the load was complete and therefore the results did not differ thereafter.

```
SELECT * FROM ErrTbl WHERE ErrCd = '635' AND ErrCd = '635'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is an issue with your query.

When you have a count conflict, Wrap your query with the select count(*) to get the accurate count. Sometimes IDE settings truncate the output or the base table changes

```
select count(*) from ( original query ) as q
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  I left out that I had an additional WHERE statement for the status.  I didn't think it was important to this discussion but I was wrong.  I adjusted the code in the original question.

It appears the query first returned 140 rows in which the error code was 635 and the status was unresolved as expected.

When I added the last 'OR ErrCd = '635' line, the OR overrode the first two WHERE conditions (status = 'unresolved' AND ErrCd = '635').  Therefore it returned 1058 rows that were all error code 635 but contained both resolved and unresolved statuses.

Just posting and asking the question helped me to think this out.

Answer (score 0):

You got different results because you ran different select , when you execute

```
SELECT *
FROM ErrTbl
WHERE status = 'unresolved'
AND ErrCd = '635'
```

Both of you condition must true

But when you run

```
SELECT *
FROM ErrTbl
WHERE status = 'unresolved'
AND ErrCd = '635'
Or ErrCd = '635'
```

If `ErrCd = '635'` come true will be enough